# SSAS - How to customize generated time dimension by SSAS wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerpivot

I created a time dimension by using the SSAS wizard in Visual Studio.
It works well, however I would like to change the generated values for date values.

In fact, the finest granularity is the date formated as ", ".

```
monday, 01/01/2014
tuesday, 02/01/2014
...
```

I would like to replace them by  format as the following example :

```
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
```

Any idea to do that ?

Comment: wizard probably created just dimension or/and table in datasource? if this is table in dataview you can add new named calculation... i would suggest do time table in your DW DB it would be easier to edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created a new view in SQL Server data source to customize my original table generated by SQL Server Dimension wizard.

This is the script to create the following view :

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DimDateCustom]
AS
SELECT        dbo.DimDate.*,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR, [PK_Date], 103) AS formattedDate
FROM            dbo.DimDate
```

You can change the last parameter for the [CONVERT() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change the destination format for the date (check Microsoft doc to get all codes)